# Open file in read mode doesn't let me delete the files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple tail like program in Python 3. My objective is to open an existing file in readonly mode and let me print out new lines that are added to the file. I would also like to handle a situation that the file may be deleted and it should stop following. The follow operation is working fine but it prevents me from deleting the files to test. I'm getting an error that the file is in use by System.

This is my follow script.

```
import os

def follow(filename):   
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as f:
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            yield line
```

I then import this follow program to my other program and invoke `__next__()` method to print the new line. I'm not sure why Python is locking the file although I ask for it open in read only mode.

Comment: Is your reporting the lock? Or is it the other program (the one that is doing the writing to the file)?

Comment: Are you deleting it using this script or some other?

Comment: I'm just deleting from windows explorer to just simulate a delete operation. I'm also simulating the write operation by opening the file and entering some random text. it follows those lines fine but when I close it and try to delete it, I couldn't

Comment: I'm sure you can force deletion of the file (overriding the error), search for "force file deletion in windows", but i'm not sure it's a good idea

Comment: I'm not able to do that while my program is running. I want to be able to follow while allowing deletion

Comment: You can't. Even if you could, how Python would retreive contents of a deleted file? It keeps in memory the file descriptor of the given file, if it is removed and a new file with the same name is created, the file descriptor will unlikely be the same.
You could implement a worker that check for modification of the given file name. Using watchdog for example. You then open the file at the offset X (saved from the previous call) and print out new lines.

Comment: can I get a python example of above watchdog approach? And does it work with large files? For ex: if my file is created at 1 AM, the size could be under 1 MB but after a few hours it grows to hundreds of megs.